# Read csv in buffer, check if it passes checks -> forward info line by line to method

Tags: java, csv

In my program I can read a csv file. Line by line I parse info to a method. BUT if the csv doesn't pass the if check, i don't want to call "otherMethod(id, new);" at all. So the whole CSV has to pass, before calling otherMethod.

So my question is: How can I read in the whole csv in some kind of buffer, check if it passes the if check and process it afterwards (line by line)?

```
boolean csvPassed = true;
int index = 0;
double id = Double.NaN, new = Double.NaN;

while ((String line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line); 
    scanner.useDelimiter(";"); 
    while (scanner.hasNext()) { 
        //check the csv line by line
        if (index == 0) 
            id = Integer.parseInt(data);
        else if (index == 1) {
            new = Integer.parseInt(data); 
            if (new == 10)
                  csvPassed = false
        }
        //whatever you want to do here
    }
}

//after the file is checked
if(csvPassed){
    // If the csv passes the check, call the method line by line...
    otherMethod(id, new);
}
```

Comment: If the csv is not very large you can read all the numbers into an `ArrayList`. If it is large then you need to make two passes through the csv. Note that you can stop processing additional lines as soon as you see that the value is 10. Finally, your variable named `new` needs to be renamed.

Comment: Did my answer below solve your problem? If so, then it would be nice if you accept it, if not then leave a comment stating your problem please.

Answer (score 3):

This may help you.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("<YOUR_FILENAME>"));
//your buffer to store the lines of your csv
List<Integer[]> lines = new LinkedList<>();
//a flag to indicate the success
boolean passed = true;
//read in the file line by line
String currentLine;
while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
    //split the line up at your delimiter
    String[] lineSplit = currentLine.split(";");
    //the array to store the parsed integers of the current line
    Integer[] parsedLine = new Integer[lineSplit.length];

    //process each element of that line and check for your condition
    for(int i = 0; i < lineSplit.length; i++){
        //make sure you can parse that string
        parsedLine[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[i]);
        if(parsedLine[i] == 10){
            //Maybe you could also exit your loop here and clear the list?
            passed = false;
        }
    }
    //add this line to your buffer
    lines.add(parsedLine);
}

//If all lines passed the condition, process line by line out of your buffer
if(passed){
    //make sure you have the 2 values in the array
    for(Integer[] line : lines){
        otherMethod(line[0], line[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: He wants to read the while file in some kind of buffer, and if all lines pass the check to not contain a "10" then he wants to call another method line by line?